# Leaflet Layer Control: select Layer inside Layer Group?

Tags: leaflet

I would like to have a Leaflet Layer Control where I can select one of the base layers, and have this base layer itself be a LayerGroup from which I can select sublayers to display. I'm thinking of a setup where I click a radio button to select the base layer (the layer group), and under that I would then see a list of checkboxes for which layers within that to show. Is there a way to do this using the stock Layer Control?

I looked for examples and thumbed through the Leaflet API but didn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no Leaflet support for layer hierarchies beyond the LayerGroup level.  You could use the [Leaflet.GroupedLayerControl plugin](https://github.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol) to achieve some basic grouping in the layer control panel, but not an actual hierarchy.

Comment: I ended up writing my own control to do this-- it wasn't that bad.

Comment: Please share if you can! :)

Comment: Oh my. I was only there for one summer :)

Comment: How can I show only tooltips like this? Without any marker in a geojson oneachlayer